# How to run exe before or after "RunProgram" from 7zip sfx files setting on config.txt?

Tags: windows, linux, sfx, 7zip

I am using 7zip to pack an installation (im using 7z because i need it to work in linux and windows).

From what i've been reading the config.txt file can contains this:

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
RunProgram="Installer.exe"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

But what if i need to run another exe before or after running installer.exe? Is it possible like it is in NSIS?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify another progrem in 'RUnProgram' config parameter. Lets say its some .bat file. At the moment program is run, files are already extracted at TEMP location. As your .bat will run then, it can call Installer.exe once script is finished preparations.